# error: 'make_array' is not a member of 'boost::serialization

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost, mingw

I am unable to compile a [basic boost vector example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/vector.htm).
I am on Windows 10, and I am using the [nuwen MinGW distro](https://nuwen.net/mingw.html) version 15.0, without git included. This version contains GCC 7.10 and Boost 1.64. I have unpacked MinGw and placed it in the root of my file system and I am following the MinGW usage instruction A to run set_distro_paths.bat. Below is the code, which is failing to build on my system:

vector-fail.cpp:

```
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp>
#include <boost/numeric/ublas/io.hpp>

int main () {
    using namespace boost::numeric::ublas;
    vector<double> v (3);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < v.size (); ++ i)
        v (i) = i;
    std::cout << v << std::endl;
}
```

Makefile:

```
vector-fail: vector-fail.o
    g++ vector-fail.o -o vector-fail
vector-fail.o: vector-fail.cpp
    g++ -c vector-fail.cpp -o vector-fail.o
```

Output:

```
g++ -c vector-fail.cpp -o vector-fail.o
In file included from C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/vector.hpp:21:0,
                 from vector-fail.cpp:1:
C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp: In member function 'void 
boost::numeric::ublas::unbounded_array<T, ALLOC>::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int)':
C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:299:33: error: 'make_array' is not a member of 'boost::serialization'
              ar & serialization::make_array(data_, s);
                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:299:33: note: suggested alternative: 'make_nvp'
             ar & serialization::make_array(data_, s);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
                             make_nvp
C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp: In member function 'void boost::numeric::ublas::bounded_array<T, N, ALLOC>::serialize(Archive&, unsigned int)':
C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:494:33: error: 'make_array' is not a member of 'boost::serialization'
             ar & serialization::make_array(data_, s);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
C:\MinGW\include/boost/numeric/ublas/storage.hpp:494:33: note: suggested alternative: 'make_nvp'
             ar & serialization::make_array(data_, s);
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~
                                 make_nvp
make: *** [Makefile:5: vector-fail.o] Error 1
```

Unfortunately none of those errors are occurring within my code, rather they are caused by files within include files within the boost library its self. What changes could be made in application level code or the Makefile to allow the program to compile?

Comment: How did you install boost?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes this is an issue with the ublas headers. I ran into it before. You can workaround it by including

```
#include <boost/serialization/array_wrapper.hpp>
```

before that point though. I'd consider reporting it to the maintainers of the ublas code.

Comment: This works! But only when you put the include for array_wrapper before the include for vector.

Comment: its 2017 and still no fix?

Comment: @Knowledge It was 2017 in June too, for your information.

Comment: @sehe _answered Jun 14 at 12:12_ I also read that ublast hasnt been _significantly_ updated since 2009, so :D I guess I'll stick with numerical recepies

Comment: @Knowledge Yeah, so hardly a month ago. _[Did you think Jun '14?]_ TTBOMK, NR hasn't been updated since 1996 (my copy, being C, since 1992), unless you refer to the ICTP version which ... requires flash, so I dunno. On a sidenote, ublast sounds like an awesome name for a library :)

Comment: @Knowledge found a relevant PR and nudged it https://github.com/uBLAS/ublas/pull/55#issuecomment-316985022

Comment: And [renudged](https://github.com/uBLAS/ublas/pull/55#issuecomment-736195988), 3 years down the road, the PR still merges cleanly. I'm not sure I'd hold my breath at this point